# How to display correct monetary value in Datadog Dashboard Widget

Tags: java, metrics, datadog

I've created a custom Datadog metric in a Springboot Java App, and turned on the management end-points.

I am incrementing a MeterRegistry Counter with a double value (relating to the monetary value of an order)
When I use the /management/metrics end-point, I can see the correct value being stored.

However, when I create a widget in my Datadog dashboard, it is only displaying the pre-decimal point value of the data. e.g the order value is 61.67 and in Datadog it is displaying 61, so it's not even doing any rounding !

Is there any way to display the raw value of the counter in a Datadog Dashboard widget?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, I would check what metrics are being stored in Datadog with the [API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#query-timeseries-points)
2. Second, I would check the type of metric you are sending `https://app.datadoghq.com/metric/summary?metric=<my-metric>` Not sure if a counter type can have decimal values, maybe a gauge would be more appropriate.
3. Finally, to display a value you can use a query value widget such as the one in the snippet below. Make sure to:

   - Take the last value (here aggregator: last)
   - Select the number of decimals of interest (here precision: 3)
   - Select the right space aggregation if you receive this metric from multiple places (i.e. multiple tags) (here avg:my_metric{*})

```
{
  "viz": "query_value",
  "requests": [
    {
      "q": "avg:nginx.logs.request.count{*}.as_count()",
      "type": null,
      "style": {
        "palette": "dog_classic",
        "type": "solid",
        "width": "normal"
      },
      "aggregator": "last",
      "conditional_formats": [
        {
          "comparator": ">",
          "palette": "white_on_red",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "comparator": ">=",
          "palette": "white_on_yellow",
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "comparator": "<",
          "palette": "white_on_green",
          "value": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "autoscale": true,
  "precision": "3"
}
```

**Side note**: I also use this for Kafka (just as a reference) but it should not be required in your case:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-javaagent:dd-java-agent.jar","-Ddd.agent.host=localhost","-Ddd.jmxfetch.statsd.host=localhost","-Ddd.trace.global.tags=env:kafka","-Ddd.agent.port=8126","-Ddd.service.name=KafkaProducer","-Ddd.logs.injection=true","-Ddd.trace.analytics.enabled=true","-Ddd.kafka.analytics.enabled=true","-Ddd.servlet.analytics.enabled=true","-Ddd.spring-web.analytics.enabled=true","-jar","target/KafkaConsumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. The java io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.Counter object can increment both Integers and Doubles, Datadog apparently converts these values to a rate. Thank you for the heads up about gauge.